# How do web sites implement the handling of many email boxes on their domain?

Tags: domains, email

I apologize if this is off topic, but I just can't figure out how sites like `https://www.guerrillamail.com/` and `http://www.throwawaymail.com/` implement so many email boxes in their domains?

The paradigm of temporary email is basically that a temporary email is generated on some domain, which expires after a set period of time. Clearly if the service is popular, the domain might be handling thousands of email boxes in the domain. However most hosting plans only allow a few tens of email addresses on a domain. Google domains for example allows up to 100 aliases on the domain to be forwarded.

What is the trick to supporting so many email boxes on the domain?

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic, questions here are required to be about a [website under your control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), otherwise we'll end up with answers that really cannot be confirmed one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

There are also so many websites like this, and all the domain registered by them self, **you can not spoof someone domain to send email.**

They are using own SMTP server to create large number of emails and delete them after few minutes/hours.

Here is [Github Repo](https://github.com/flashmob/Guerrilla-SMTPd) for that service.

Most of all mails goes into spam folder, once some people report it as spam. For example, you have got one mail from user@example.com, and report it as spam, so other mail from same domain will goes into Spam folder.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking how you can create so many email accounts when most hosting plans or providers limit how many accounts you can have.

The answer is that if you own the server and have full control, you can do anything you like.  You could have a completely separate mail server, or even a number of them.  If you wanted you could have squillions of email addresses.

The only limitation is that imposed by the hosting service.  If you are the hosting service you can do what you like.

(or maybe I am way off topic :P )